# Analyze Drupal and Wordpress sites CPU load in shared server

Tags: wordpress, drupal, analytics, load, cpu

Our hosting company  is complaining that both our Drupal and Wordpress websites running in a shared server are consuming too many CPU resources. The traffic for each site is not more than 100 users per day and, at a first glance, we don't have very many plugins/add-ons.

Is there any tool or resource to analyse what is causing that high CPU load?

Thanks

Update: We decided to suspend our accounts while the problem was being debugged but still our hosting (Site5) said that they saw unacceptable activity on our sites so we had to move to a dedicated server... asked them several times to provide us with more information and they always came back saying that we had to purchase a higher account. Finally decided to move to another hosting service.

Answer (score 1):

It's more important if one or more of your plugins is a known resource hog, not how many plugins you use or not. Try to implement caching if you don't have yet, that's always a good starting point. For wordpress install [W3 Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/) or [WP Super Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/).

See this draft about [Testing Wordpress Performance](http://codex.wordpress.org/Testing_WordPress_Performance).

Do you have some webanalytics software installed (Google Analytics, Piwik...)? Can you see if there are some traffic spikes around certain times?

And yes, as Randy-e suggested, change your provider if they are not able to support you with more details. For every webserver out there do modules and extensions exist that are able to distribute the resources in a nice way between the customers.

Comment: +1 for using decent caching. For Drupal there's the [boost](http://drupal.org/project/boost) module, which is great if the majority of your users aren't authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is for shared hosting.

You may only have 100 users per day...but how many of them are using the site at the same time? What does your hosts ToS state about CPU Usage? (i.e. what do they consider high). You could also ask your host what they see going on. Any host worth their salt will provide you with more information than just "you're using too many resources." Ask them what specifically is using too many resources, what times it's happening at, etc. Your best bet is to ask them. They have the access to the server, they can see what is causing the issue.

I'd recommend you get a jump on it though, because they're likely to just suspend your account.

But with that many users you're starting to encroach on VPS territory if there's a group of them that are accessing at the same time. One User browsing isn't going to use hardly any resources, however if you have 15 users browsing at the same time, they're likely using too much.

From the sounds of it, you've outgrown shared hosting for your type of site though.

Check if there are any plugins for wordpress that will help you analyze load. I don't know of any for Drupal...but I'm sure wordpress has them. I know MyBB has tools built into it so I can't see Wordpress not.